# trying to understant connected component

Tags: general-topology

Now, I am studying connected component. It is known that connected component is an equivalence classes hence every connected components are disjoint. I confuse with term disjoint in here.

Unit interval $[0,1]$ is connected and $A_1=[0,\frac{1}{4}], A_2= [\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}], A_3=[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}], A_4=[\frac{3}{4},1]$ are connected components of $X$. Aren't they? Further, $A_i\cap A_{i+1}\neq\emptyset$.

From the example above I can conclude that if $X$ is connected and $\{C_i:i\in I\}$ is collection of components of $X$ then $C_i\cap C_{i+1}\neq\emptyset$.Please tell me that my conclusion is true in general.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Connected_components

Answer (score 0):

No they are not $A$ has got one connected component namely $A$. Let us go back to definition. A connected component $A$ is a **maximal connected subset** of $A$.

So for instance when $A$ is connected it has only one connected component namely itself.

When $A$ is the disjoint union of connected subsets it has finitely many connected components. The connected components of $]0,1)\cup (2,3]$ are $]0,1)$ and $(2,3]$

Etc